# OpenWRT add permanent virtual interface

Tags: networking, network-interface, openwrt, router

I have **OpenWRT** on my router (Turris Omnia). How can I add permanent virtual if or second IP to eth0 (wan)? If I use ip a a or ifconfig virtual interface will disappear after network restart or reboot. I have experience in centOS and Debian but Im new to OpenWRT. Can you please give me an advice in this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Network configuration on OpenWRT is handled by the UCI subsystem and `netifd` daemon. Main network configuration lives in `/etc/config/network`

You can add your interface to this file and issue the following command to reload network configuration `/etc/init.d/network reload`

For more information see the following manual page
[Basic Networking on OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/base-system/basic-networking)